# Recorrido virtual de un nuevo usuario

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estoy intentando hacer un "recorrido" para nuevos usuarios en una plataforma, pero no recuerdo su nombre en especifico para buscar más información.

Es cuando uno ingresa por primera vez a una plataforma, y te muestran burbujas explicando un poco la interfaz y dando el recorrido para que no te sientas perdido.

¿Cúal es su nombre o como puedo buscarlo? de este modo podré investigar más en detalle

Gracias

Comment: Te sirve Shepherd Js ? https://shepherdjs.dev

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, es lo que buscaba